# Easier way to do non-recursive list on gcs bucket outside appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a gcs file hierarchy that has a few directory under my bucket and each directory has tons of files. I want to query on my bucket and return all the directories.

I am currently outside appengine so I am using `google-api-services-storage` sdk, however it seems that the `list` query is returning every leaf files instead. As I said in the beginning as the number of my directory is fairly small but number of files in each directory is huge, I really hope I won't need to touch what is within each directory when I do the listing.

(By saying that, I know that there is actually no "directory" in gcs, just simply file object with different naming hierarchy but in `appengine` it is allowing gcs client to set whether to do the listing recursively or not, and the query performs really fast. I am wondering whether there might anything similar outside `appengine`

I searched on the [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list) however it seems to have no relevant parameters that I could config the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AE gcs client is using the delimiter and prefix options (from the [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list) you mentioned, though it uses the XML API) for simulating a non-recursive folder listing.

You can achieve that by setting the prefix to the path of the "folder" to list and setting the delimiter to '/' (or whatever is your path delimiter).

Also, I recommend looking at [gcloud-java-storage](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java/tree/master/gcloud-java-storage) for an easier to use API that is not specific to AE.