# gcloud-java-storage Storage.BlobListOption.recursive(false) not working

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud-java

I am trying to do an non-recursive list using [gcloud-java storage](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java/tree/master/gcloud-java-storage) on GCS bucket outside appengine based on [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35567550/easier-way-to-do-non-recursive-list-on-gcs-bucket-outside-appengine)

However it seems that its not working as expected, namely it is still listing all the files although I have set the `Storage.BlobListOption.recursive(false)`

my code structure is basically like:
    
    `Storage client = StorageOptions.defaultInstance().service();
    Page<Blob> blobPage = client.list(my_bucket, Storage.BlobListOption.recursive(false));
    for (Blob blob : blobPage.values()) {
      // it is still iterating all the leaf files in my_bucket
    }`

Actually later on I found that it seems that none of `BlobListOption` seems to be taking affect (`maxResults`, `prefix`) and list will just return all leaf files no matter what...

Am I using the API wrong or what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug with non-recusrive blob and prefix (folder) listing.
This was fixed in since v 0.1.15 (see [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java/commit/d930b4bbc2833d82ce84c13e3c6704695aebd91c)). The recursive option
was replaced with currentDirectory and now you can get the prefixes/child
folders. If this does not work for you or you think any of the other options does not work as intended please file an [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java/issues) and it will be
taken care of quickly.